# How can I copy data from several tables and save to several CSV files?

Tags: r, sql-server

I am trying to use R to copy all data from several tables in SQL Server, to several CSV files on my hard-drive.  I guess it will look something like this...

```
library(RODBC)
library(XLConnect)


dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=ServerName;database=DB_Name;trusted_connection=true')

# something here...

write.csv(currTableDF,file=paste("C:/Users/file_Name.csv",sep=""),row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Or do you have a question about something here?

Comment: what is your question exactly? you made some statements, but what needs to be answered?

Comment: I am getting this error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The request for procedure 'PIDs' failed because 'PIDs' is a table object. Where 'PIDs' is the name of the table that I am trying to export data from.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
install.packages("RODBC")
install.packages("dplyr")
library("RODBC")

conn <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=ServerName;database=DB_Name;trusted_connection=true')

data <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM Your_Table;")
write.csv(data,file=paste("C:/Users/file_Name.csv",sep=""),row.names=FALSE)
```